# !! ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_2_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4982, 12)

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am new in Deep Learning, and I'm trying to create this simple LSTM architecture in Keras using Google Colab:

1. Input layer of 12 input neurons
2. One Recurrent hidden layer of 1 hidden neuron for now
3. Output layer of 1 output neuron

The original error was:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_2_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4982, 12).
```

Then I tried:

```
input_shape=train_x.shape[1:]
```

But I got:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Then I tried:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, X_train.shape + (1,))
```

But I got another error again:

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

Then I tried:

```
train_x = np.reshape(train_x, (train_x.shape[0], 1, train_x.shape[1]))
```

But it didn't work:

```
Must pass 2-d input
```

Here is my original code:

```
df_tea = pd.read_excel('cleaned2Apr2019pt2.xlsx')
df_tea.head()

train_x, valid_x = model_selection.train_test_split(df_tea,random_state=2, stratify=df_tea['offer_Offer'])

train_x.shape #(4982, 12)
valid_x.shape #(1661, 12)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=train_x.shape, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_x, valid_x,
                    epochs=10,
                    batch_size=128,
                    validation_split=0.2)
```

I have looked through several stackoverflow and github suggestions for a similar problem, but none works.

Could someone help me please as I don't understand why all these methods failed.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code, timesteps = 1 (in LSTM terminology), input_dim = 12. Hence you should let
`input_shape = (1,12)`
A general formula is `input_shape = (None, timesteps, input_dim)` or 
`input_shape = (timesteps, input_dim)`

An example:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
n_examples = 4982 #number of examples
n_ft = 12 #number of features
train_x= np.random.randn(n_examples, n_ft)
#valid_x.shape #(1661, 12)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(1, n_ft), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: Oh I understand! Thanks for your help!:)